# Android Navigation Component: prevent configChanges of single fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm tyring to implement the new Android Navigation Components in my andorid app, and I've moved from a multi-activity logic, to a single activity with multiple fragments approach, as suggested by google.

One of my screens (used to be an activity, now is a fragment) renders a WebView that loads an HTML string (may contain Videos, twitter/instagram embeds and text), along with some other views (image galeries). My main problem is that when the user rotates the phone, the webview starts loading from the begining, and loses the user's scroll position. After searching, I've decided that handling configChanges manually for this particular fragment is the correct way to go, instead of letting android reload the whole fragment, since saving and restoring the WebView's state does not seem to work properly.

However, since I've moved to a single activity approach, if I do this, I'll have to handle configChanges manually for my whole app, which I do not want to do.

Is there a way to only handle configChanges manually in a single fragment, or should I move this fragment to its own activity, as it used to be, and add the configChanges code only there?

Comment: To handle the configuration changes of whole app you can use `ViewModel` and for webView handle by your self.

Comment: I do not want to prevent the app form handling configuration changes. There is one particular fragment where the HTML string is loaded that I want to prevent from getting recreated when the user rotates their phone. I could not seem to find a solution to this, so I moved this fragment in a separate activity, for now. This however, breaks my integration with the Navigaiton component, and kind of defeats its purpose.